# how to display multi lines in single choice items alert dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am displaying list of items in an alert dialog with single choice item mode with out any issues.
How can i display each items text in two lines if the length is exceeds the max width size.
list items are loading dynamically, so we can't edit them by \n break point.

Can any one please help me out in this.

Appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Sathish

---

Thanks for your reply,
Here i am using AlertDialog.Builder to show dialog with default options

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setTitle("Select the Dealershipname");

     builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selectedDealershipname , new OnClickListener() 
     { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
       {


          dialog.cancel();

       }
       });

     builder.show();
```

Here i am not using any android.R.id.Text1 kind of layout. so how can i change the properties of textview here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use setSingleLine(false) on the TextViews inside the Dialog list. You can get a reference to the textview by using a custom ArrayAdapter:

```
        String[] items = {"foo foo foo foo foo foo foo", "bar bar bar bar bar bar", "foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar"};

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items) {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // User super class to create the View
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // TextView title =
                // (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                tv.setSingleLine(false);

                return v;
            }
        };
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but if i use ListAdapter i am not getting radio buttons for each element.

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck implementing a custom ArrayAdapter where you can make changes to the layout of the list items programmatically inside the adapter. See here: [Custom ArrayAdapter Tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter).

In addition to the custom adapter, you can use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` as the layout you pass to the ArrayAdapter. It will still use `android.R.id.text1` for its TextView, and will automatically handle the RadioButton without further intervention from you.